# "ERROR: generation expression is not immutable" why is the alter table for new generated column is immutable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, generated-columns

Why is the below code not valid. I have only used immutable columns.
Below code is supposed to add a new column to the users table. There are few conditions that needs to meet for the is_valid column to be true else it will be false. The email and legacy_password columns must not be null or empty. And expiry_date must not be passed.

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS vnext.users
ADD COLUMN is_valid boolean GENERATED ALWAYS AS
 ((
    Case when (((trim(coalesce(email,'')) <> '') IS NOT False) 
    AND ((trim(coalesce(legacy_password,'')) <> '') IS NOT False)
    AND (Case WHEN expiry_date is null Then True ELSE date_trunc('day', 
    expiry_date)>date_trunc('day', current_timestamp) END)) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
  )) STORED;
```

Comment: You can’t use current _timestamp, it’s value changes every microsecond, it’s not immutable

Comment: Is there a way to check if `expiry_date`  is passed without breaking immutability?

Comment: Which date? The value of `current_timestamp` when you wrote the question is a different value then when I wrote this comment.

Comment: Sorry I meant `expiry_date` column

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the use of the `current_timestamp` in the query made it mutable, and got the above error. Removing the `current_timestamp` should work for now.

Not sure if there's a way to check if the `expiry_date` is expired without being mutable.

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS vnext.users
ADD COLUMN is_valid boolean GENERATED ALWAYS AS
 ((
    Case when (((trim(coalesce(email,'')) <> '') IS NOT False) 
    AND ((trim(coalesce(legacy_password,'')) <> '') IS NOT False))
    THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
  )) STORED;
```

Comment: You can simplify that expression to `( trim(coalesce(email,'')) <> '' and trim(coalesce(legacy_password,'')) <> '')`

Answer (score 1):

current_timestamp is obviously not immutable.

Also, date_trunc when the 2nd parameter is a timestamptz is only stable, because the result it gives depends on your session's timezone setting.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can overcome the problem of `current_timestamp` not being `IMMUTABLE` is to use a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger instead of a generated column. The trigger function can simply assign the value to the `boolean` column, and you are not restricted to `IMMUTABLE` expressions.

The difference is that the trigger only runs at a certain point in time, while a generated column guarantees that the generated value will **always** be equal to the result of the generation expression. Hence the requirement for immutability.